# What's the best way to support deprecated methods which are replaced by new ones?

Tags: android, webview, deprecated

I like to use the findAll/ findAllAsync method in android.webkit.WebView. findAll is deprecated and Google suggests to use findAllAsync which requires Jelly Bean or higher. However, I like my application to support 2.2+. I tried to the following, but I get warning for findAll (deprecation) and error for findAllAysnc (need to increment minimum SDK version):

```
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
          myWebView.findAll(query);         
      else
      {
          myWebView.findAllAsync(query);
      }
```

What's the best way to deal with this? Should I just use findAll and ignore the deprecation warning?

Answer (score 0):

Use findAll and if the warning is really too annoying add a `@SuppressWarning("deprecation")` annotation to suppress it explicitly.

One problem with this is that when you use this annotation on your method you might miss other deprecated calls as it will apply to the whole method.

Comment: My mistake, the correct annotation argument is "deprecation", "dep-ann" is for old javadoc deprecated if I remember well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer goes in several ways:

What are you setting as min SDK version and target SDK version in the manifest ?

Same question, but in Eclipse (or whatever IDE you're using) for Android build API properties ?

(I'm answering as if your question is "how do I get rid of the android lint warning", rather than "how do I fix the warning correctly" .. )

Answer (score 0):

There's a very interesting and powerful way of doing what you want, and it is called reflection. From the Oracle's [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/):

> Reflection is commonly used by programs which require the ability to
>   examine or modify the runtime behavior of applications running in the
>   Java virtual machine. This is a relatively advanced feature and should
>   be used only by developers who have a strong grasp of the fundamentals
>   of the language.

In short, **reflection** allows you to find out if class is defined, you can find out its methods and properties, and invoke a class' functionality... all at runtime!

I have an app that needs to handle the audio focus on Android 2.1 devices but the Audio Focus is not available for those versions, so I use this technique. It is, by the way, a bumpy road. I would suggest reading carefully the documentation and try to follow some examples.

Comment: Reflection has a lot more overhead than virtual method calls, while this is a powerful tool, it's kind of like using a sledgehammer to put a nail in the wall.

Comment: Reflection can definitely be used for this kind of things and is indeed very powerfull and allow checking at runtime if an API is available. However I think it's not a good idea to avoid a compilation warning and  really overkill for such a simple use case.

Comment: @edthethird I totally agree, and it's a hell of a job, but if the requirement is a 'must' this is an elegant way to go.